# Typescript error - Cannot find name 'process'. in Yarn berry workspace

Tags: typescript, monorepo, typechecking, yarn-workspaces, yarn-berry

I am configuring a monorepo using yarn berry workspace.

So I created the next.js 13.4 project in the services folder (yarn create next-app)
Next project creation has been completed.

And I entered the type check command to check the type of the project, but the following error occurred.

```
error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node`.

12     images: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STATIC_LINK}/web/resources/image/Link_bi.png`,
                  ~~~~~~~
```

The error message is that the type cannot be found.

After searching, I added types:['node'] to my `tsconfig.json`.

Again I got the following error:

```
Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point of type library 'node' specified in compilerOptions

  tsconfig.json:12:15
    12     "types": ["node"],
```

I'm guessing that the types module can't be found because I'm using the yarn berry workspace, but I don't know how to solve it.

I would appreciate your help.

tsconfig is being used by extending tsconfig.base.json from the root.

```
//tsconfig.base.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  }
}
```

```
// tsconfig.json of the project in question
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts", "**/*.mts", "**/*.json", "global.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules", "**/.*/"]
}
```

The following is package.json of the project in question.

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.2.2",
     ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.5.7",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7"
  }
}
```